# Passing dynamically allocated array through constructor

Tags: c++, arrays

Below I have a custom constructor, that takes in an array, the array size, and name of the set as per my instructors specifications. However, when I run this program I am getting a segmentation core dump. The set being referred to here is a data member ( int *set) and psize is the physical size of the array. How can I fix this?

```
//custom constructor
Set::Set( int array[] , int size, char name ){

        set = new int[size];

        psize = ( size > 0 ? size: DEFAULTSIZE);
        numOfElements = size;

        set = array;

        if (!set){
                cout << "Cannot Allocate Memory, exiting program... " << endl;
                exit(1);
        }

        Set::name = name;
}

ostream &operator<<( ostream &out, const Set &s){

    cout << "The Elements of your set are: " << endl;
    cout << "{" ;
    for ( int i = 0; i < s.numOfElements; i++){
            out << s.set[i];
            if ( i < s.numOfElements - 1){
                    out << ',';
            }
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;
    cout << "Number of Elements is  " << s.getNumOfElements() << endl;
}

int main(){
        int arr1[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        int arr2[3] = {2, 4, 11};

        Set A( arr1, 10, 'A');
        Set B( arr2, 3, 'B');
        cout << A;
        cout << B;

        /*Set C;
        cin >> C;
        cout << C;

        Set D(A);

        cout << D;

        Set E = A + C;
        cout << E;
*/
}
```

Comment: post a complete example. before posting it, reduce it to minimum and make sure that it still compiles and exemplifies the problem.

Comment: My program compiled properly, however, when I try to run the program it says it has been core dumped. It displayed a random stretch of numbers

Comment: Rolled back the latest edit since it changed the code significantly after an answer was posted. @ChynnaHernandez: please don't do that. You can amend the question, but please don't *change* it after answers have been posted.

Comment: You can post a new question about problems in a fixed version, but asking about every problem encountered in a debugging session is going to be sloooooow.

Comment: how is set declared?? int* set?

Comment: I'm a beginner, I am unfamiliar with how this works, I am trying my best to understand concepts

Comment: post the class declaration ..

Comment: @basav set is declared as int *set

Comment: `set = new int[size]` is overwritten by `set = array` just below; maybe you meant to copy from array into set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if set is declared as int* set, then , it would be better to first allocate memory/clone it  before you acess it.

```
set = new int[size];
```

Then, you can acess it in your overloaded operator <<.

```
 s.set[i];
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience @basav . I fixed the code as per your suggestions, but somewhere I am still getting an invalid pointer. I am unsure as to where this invalid pointer is coming from

Comment: if you comment out this line, it works fine right?? //out << s.set[i];

Comment: If I comment out that line, however, I will not be able to see if it would work. My program compiles either way, but I will not be able to see it if I comment it out. Does this make sense?

Comment: increase alloation size and try it once..set = new int[size+1]..

Comment: thanks for your help! I was able to figure out my problem. I am trying to assign the contents of array, into the contents of set, so it should be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, you store the size in `psize` (twice), but in your `operator<<` you reference `numOfElements`, which is uninitialized and therefore has garbage in it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I ran the program, and this time is displayed the set correctly, but then it displayed a memory map and core dumped, i posted the edited version.